# Excel 2016 file ignoring links and grant access using applescript

Tags: excel, macos, file, applescript

The problem i am having is that i am always receiving new spreadsheets and if i run the code below.

```
set resultWorkBook to "/Users/x/Desktop/myfile.xmls"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set resultWorkbook to open workbook workbook file name posix_file without update links
    end tell
```

It will try to open the spreadsheet but then come up with the dialog window asking whether to grant access or not.

If I run the same spreadsheet like this.

```
tell application "Finder
set filecontents to file of folder Desktop of (path to home folder)
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set display alerts to false
        set resultWorkbook to open filecontents
end tell
```

It will open the workbook without asking for access but then comes up asking me to choose one of three options regarding links in the spreadsheet.

I really need the best of both worlds, and wondered if anyone could give me a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the posix path (a string) to a `file` object, like this

```
set posix_file to "/Users/x/Desktop/myfile.xmls" as POSIX file
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set resultWorkBook to open workbook workbook file name posix_file without update links
end tell
```

---

Update; the difference is the `as POSIX file`command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is, opening the workbook will fix the link issue but does not resolve the grant access issue in os x 10.11. yet if i use my second example to open the spreadsheet, it will open without concerns regarding granting access but then will complain about links. I need to be able to use both in one open command.

Comment: My script works here, no issue with links and grant access (**OS X 10.11.5**), but you must try it. In my script the  `posix_file` variable contain an **file object**, not a **string** as in your script

Comment: Thanks jackjr300 for pointing that out. I will give this a try and hopefully this will be the end to my issue with sandboxing.